# Web3 from account question

Tags: web3js, truffle

Hello can anyone tell me why I would be getting an error when i type this in the Truffle develop console? ***app.setGreetings(“Hey Ladies!”, {from: web3eth.accounts[0]})***

The error it is giving is... truffle(develop)> Uncaught Error: The send transactions "from" field must be defined!

I did already store the instance the contract in a global app variable which I believe was successful. I did this with the command... ***Greetings.deployed().then(function(instance) {app = instance;})***

Not sure where the issues lies but any help would be appreciated. I am trying to run the simple exercise of setting and getting functions in my contract through the truffle develop console.

Comment: What do you get when you console log `web3eth`?

Comment: It said console.log(web3eth) is not defined.. I also tried console.log(web3eth.accounts)  and console.log(web3eth.accounts[0]) and all of them returned errors and said it was undefined. I am in "truffle develop" in my terminal though. Not sure if that matters but I don't think you can use console.log here but I am new to this so could be wrong.

Comment: Ah, right, you're in the truffle console. You should try writing `web3eth` directly then. If that doesn't work, I don't know.

Comment: As a side-note: I wholeheartedly recommend you check [Hardhat](https://hardhat.org/tutorial/) as an alternative to Truffle. It's 10x better and faster and the docs are nicer.